# How to set my geolocation fixed. Weather app, javascript - navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make a small weather app which will be on the heading of a web page. It needs to display

the temperature and a small icon regarding the weather situation thats going outside. The problem is

that this website is going on a screen where I wont be able to say "yes" when the page asks me whether or

not I agree for him to know my location. I need the location to stay fixed and not ask everytime I

refresh the page. It needs to load the location and the weather immediately after I refresh, without

asking me. I also need some help with the icons, I dont really know how to implement them, I found

several examples but I still dont get it how do people do it. I have downloaded the weather icon master,

I would really appreciate it if someone could just give me one example on how to add an icon, a simple

```
if (description == "Clouds")
{
LOAD PICTURE CLOUDS
}
```

yea... I dont know how to do that...

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>WETTER</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="temperature"></h1>
    <h2 id="description"></h2>
    <p id="location"></p>
    <i class="wi-day-rain"></i>
    <div class="text">
  </body>
  
  

  <script>
  function getWeather() {
  let temperature = document.getElementById("temperature");
  let description = document.getElementById("description");
  let location = document.getElementById("location");
  let weatherpic;
  let api = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";
  let apiKey = "f146799a557e8ab658304c1b30cc3cfd";
  
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
  function success(position) {
    latitude = 47.058700;
    longitude = 15.457632;
    let url =   //not here 
      api +
      "?lat=" +
      latitude +
      "&lon=" +
      longitude +
      "&appid=" +
      apiKey +
      "&units=imperial"; 


       fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        var temp = data.main.temp;
        temp = (temp - 32) * 5/9;
        temp = temp.toFixed(1);
        temperature.innerHTML = temp + "° C";
        
    
        temperature.innerHTML = temp;    // OUTPUT
        location.innerHTML = data.name;     // OUTPUT
        description.innerHTML = data.weather[0].main;       //OUTPUT
        temperature.innerHTML = temp;
        weatherpic.innerHTML = data.weather[0].icon;
        
        var iconsrc = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + icon + ".png"
        
        
      });
      }
     
  function error() {
    location.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
  }
  
  
}


getWeather();
  
  
  </script>
  
  
  </div>
  
</html>
```

I know that this line asks me for my geolocation
`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);`

I would like to have a fixed longitude and altitude and to NEVER ask me.

Any type of help would be appreciative, hope you have a great day, all the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Instead of passing a callback to the geolocation browser request and waiting for the user to accept the request, directly fetch the weather based on the longitude and lattitude you want.

**Complete code**

```js
function getWeather() {
  let temperature = document.getElementById("temperature");
  let description = document.getElementById("description");
  let location = document.getElementById("location");

  let api = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather";
  let apiKey = "f146799a557e8ab658304c1b30cc3cfd";

  let latitude = 47.058700;
  let longitude = 15.457632;
  let url = api +
    "?lat=" +
    latitude +
    "&lon=" +
    longitude +
    "&appid=" +
    apiKey +
    "&units=imperial";


  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      var temp = data.main.temp;
      temp = (temp - 32) * 5 / 9;
      temp = temp.toFixed(1);
      temperature.innerHTML = temp + "° C";


      temperature.innerHTML = temp; // OUTPUT
      location.innerHTML = data.name; // OUTPUT
      description.innerHTML = data.weather[0].main; //OUTPUT
      temperature.innerHTML = temp;

      document.getElementById("weather-pic").src = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + data.weather[0].icon + ".png"
    });
}


getWeather();
```

```html
<h1 id="temperature"></h1>
<h2 id="description"></h2>
<p id="location"></p>
<i class="wi-day-rain"></i>
<img src="" id="weather-pic"/>
<div class="text">
```

**Weather image to show**

As the response already contains the icon to be used in `data.weather[0].icon`, simply set the image source based on the returned data:

```
document.getElementById("weather-pic").src = 
   "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + data.weather[0].icon + ".png"
```

Assuming you have an `<img id="weather-pic">` somewhere in your page.

Comment: Thank you very much, Im in a hurry and this really helped meee! Thanks man, cheers

Comment: That's good to hear! If that solved your problem, please tick the "mark as solution" check mark in the top left of the answer so your question is marked as solved.